# Assigning default value to a template parameter based on a previous template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a program like:
(please ignore how nonsensical it looks, it just a reproducible example )

```cpp
using MyUInt = unsigned int;
using MyLInt = long int;

template<class T1, class T2>
T1 fn(const T2& arg){
    return T1(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fn<int, MyUInt>(1);
    std::cout << fn<double, MyLInt>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

is it possible to assign a default value to `T2` based on `T1` so I don't have to declare it manually? What are the alternatives?

I'm looking for something like

```cpp
using MyUInt = unsigned int;
using MyLInt = long int;

template<class T1, class T2 = typename std::is_same<T1, int>::value ? MyUInt : MyLInt>
T1 fn(const T2& arg){
    return T1(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fn<int>(1);
    std::cout << fn<double>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using C++17.

Comment: Arg determines it directly I think.

Comment: Are you sure you even need `T2` to be a template parameter?

Comment: Did you try getting rid of `T2` and meta-evaluating the type of `arg` like this: `template <class T1> T1 fn(std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T1, int>, MyUInt, MyLInt> const& arg){ /* ... */ }` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use template specialization to define a helper type to handle the mapping between types, eg:

```
using MyUInt = unsigned int;
using MyLInt = long int;

template<class T>
struct myStruct {
    using type = MyLInt;
};

template<>
struct myStruct<int> {
    using type = MyUInt;
};

// define other mappings as needed...

template<class T>
using myStruct_t = typename myStruct<T>::type;

template<class T1, class T2 = myStruct_t<T1>>
T1 fn(const T2& arg){
    return T1(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fn<int>(1);
    std::cout << fn<double>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Who4Ikjsh)

---

**UPDATE**: apparently, the above will not work, since `arg` is in a deduced context, so `T2` will never use its default value, and will always be the type that is actually passed in, which in this example is `int`.

So, I would suggest a different approach - swap the meaning of the template arguments so that `arg` is deduced from the caller's input, and the return type is deduced by the helper based on the input type, eg:

```
using MyUInt = unsigned int;
using MyLInt = long int;

template<class T>
struct myStruct {
};

template<>
struct myStruct<MyLInt> {
    using type = double;
};

template<>
struct myStruct<MyUInt> {
    using type = int;
};

// define other mappings as needed...

template<class T>
using myStruct_t = typename myStruct<T>::type;

template<class T, class Ret = myStruct_t<T>>
Ret fn(const T& arg){
    return Ret(arg);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fn(MyUInt(1));
    std::cout << fn(MyLInt(1));

    // this also works
    std::cout << fn<MyUInt>(1);
    std::cout << fn<MyLInt>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/OL4AJuYCh)

Comment: This does not matches OP's description. In particular, according to OP's description, for the call `fn<int>(1);` the `T2` should be `unsigned int` but your example deduces `T2` to `int`. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/0T_qISbwN)

Comment: Hmm, it *should* be deducing `T1=int` to `T2=unsigned int`, and `T1=double` to `T2=long int`. How odd that it is not. When I comment out the default `type` in the un-specialized struct, and then try `fn<float>(1)`, it still deduces `T2=int` even though there is no specialization defined for `float`. And when I do define a specialization for `float` that maps `type` to, say, `bool`, it deduces as `int` instead. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/lEW0vkfJg) How is that even possible? Compiler bug?

Comment: It is because the default argument for `T2` is never used and `T2` is always deduced(no matter what) from the passed function argument. This is the main reason i did not write an answer because `T2` is in a deduced context and so will be deduced(unless ofcourse you explicitly pass template arg for `T2`) and there is no point in using a default argument for template parameter `T2`.

Comment: Oh. good point.  OK, I have updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: This looks better and more like what  OP asked. You're welcome.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you can fix your first solution by forcing `T2` to be non-deduced. (in C++20 we got [`std::type_identity_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) for this, in C++17 you unfortunately would have to roll your own) That would use the default of `T2` if it's not explicitly set while still allowing the caller to explicitly specify `T2`. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Kzafoc6bW)